# Adjacent element in responsive layout

Tags: css

I have a table-like structure. It looks something like this:

```
┌───────────────────────┬───────────┬────────┐
│Big column             |Info 1     |Info 2  |
╞═══════════════════════╪═══════════╪════════╡
┊......                 ┊...        ┊...     ┊
└───────────────────────┴───────────┴────────┘
```

When the browser window is too small to fit all three columns, I want it to change to this:

```
┌───────────────────────┐
│Big column             |
├──────────────┬────────┤
│Info 1        |Info 2  |
╞══════════════╧════════╡
┊......                 ┊
├──────────────┬────────┤
┊...           ┊...     ┊
└──────────────┴────────┘
```

Of note is that "Info 2" is more or less fixed with a defined maximum width (130px)

The overall layout is achieved using `display: table/table-row/table-cell` in the first case, but the only solution I have found for the second case feels hackish.

```
.cell:first-child {
    display: block;
}
.cell:nth-child(2) {
    display: inline-block;
    width: calc(100% - 130px);
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.cell:last-child {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 130px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

... Yeah. Hackish.

Is there a way to achieve this without resorting to the use of `calc()`? I have tried `float` but either the "Info 1" cell collapses to the minimum width to fit its content, or the "Info 2" cell drops one line below, neither of which work.

**EDIT:** HTML, as requested, is trivial:

```
<div id="bigtable">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Big column</div>
        <div class="cell">Info 1</div>
        <div class="cell">Info 2</div>
    </div>
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

Comment: Are you willing to use about flexbox or `display:contents`?

Comment: @Oriol I actually do use flexbox elsewhere in this project, but it must have some graceful fallback for browsers that don't support it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what [grids like Bootstrap's](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) were designed for, though you'd have to settle for breakpoints and relative widths. Consider loading [just the grid](https://github.com/zirafa/bootstrap-grid-only) (14.9KB).

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" id="bigtable">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
            <div>Big column</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-4">
            <div>Info 1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2">
            <div>Info 2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/vj863fe4/)**

Note that I've set a min-width on the container to keep your Info 2 column above 130px.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, `col-xs-8` essentially translates to "width: 8/12*100%`, or roughly `66%`. This means giving the columns percentage-based widths... Yes, that can work.

Comment: Right. In the case of nested columns, it's the same proportion of the parent column.

Comment: I meant to link to the Bootstrap grid docs. Added. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: All right. Rather than adding any of Bootstrap to the project's code, I've simply added `width:40%` and `width:60%` to the lower two cells. This works very well. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can force a row break with this trick:

- Display the rows as `table-row-group`s instead of `table-row`s
- Insert an empty element at the place where you want the break, and display it as `table-row`.

However, you want the cell in the first row to cover the same width as the two cells in the following row. This can't be achieved with CSS tables, but you can use HTML tables and the `colspan` attribute.

That will be displayed correctly. However, styling the first cell of each row with `colspan="2"` is a table model error, because there is a column with no cell. If you dislike validation errors, you can add an additional row without `colspan="2"`, and hide it with CSS. That row should have at least two cells to avoid the error, or exactly 4 to avoid a warning.

```css
#bigtable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
#bigtable tr {
  display: table-row-group;
}
#toggler:checked ~ #bigtable script {
  display: table-row;
}
#bigtable [hidden] {
  display: none;
}
/* Optional */ #bigtable tr { border: 3px solid; } #bigtable td { border: 1px solid; }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="toggler" />
<label for="toggle">Toggle table style</label>
<table id="bigtable">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Big column</td>
    <script hidden></script>
    <td class="cell">Info 1</td>
    <td class="cell">Info 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">A</td>
    <script hidden></script>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Foo</td>
    <script hidden></script>
    <td>Bar</td>
    <td>Baz</td>
  </tr>
  <tr hidden><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Definitely an interesting way to do it. I've gone with isherwood's answer, but this definitely is a valid solution.